# Два обработчика (Touch и Pinch) на SKCanvas Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

Всем привет пишу своё первое приложение на Xamarin и у меня возникла возможно нестадартная проблема
у меня есть

`<skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvasView" Grid.RowSpan="2" PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" EnableTouchEvents="True"> </skia:SKCanvasView>`

я реализовал отличную механику отслеживания координат нажатия мне помог TouchTracker
Однако у меня возникла необходимость отслеживания жеста увеличения
и тут начался конфликт) события одного обработчика перехватывают события другого (в результате конфликта я нашел более простое событие Touch из SKTouchEventArgs, но от этого проблемы не ушли)

```
  private void OnTouching(object sender, SKTouchEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.ActionType)
        {
            case SKTouchAction.Released:

                 Debug.Write("Палец отжат!");

               
                
                break;
            case SKTouchAction.Moved:
                Debug.Write("Движение!");
                if (Pressed == true)
                {
                    Moved = true;
                }
                break;
            case SKTouchAction.Pressed:
                Debug.Write("Палец нажат");
                Pressed = true;
                Moved = false;
                break;

        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

после добавления

`var pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer(); pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += (s, e) =>{ Debug.WriteLine("PinchTracked"); //  //  DisplayAlert("Жест увеличения ", "Вы нажали на: {listSvgHelper[i].Name}", "ОК"); };`

В зависимости закомментирована ли эта строка `e.Handled = true;`  илии нет работают один обработчик или оба (но один с ограничениями)

как выйти из ситуации

Comment: Мне нужно именно координаты клика (поэтому событие Tapped из TapGestureRecognizer мне не нужно))
для примера того что я хочу сделать можно посмотреть приложение Mark'o travel и работу с картой там там есть клики и увеличение)) только проект написан на java.
Пытаюсь сделать тоже самое но на c#